# How to convert current date and time format in milliseconds (only 10 digits)?

Tags: android, date-format, moodle, milliseconds, android-date

I have converted date format in `milliseconds` and time format in `milliseconds`. I am getting current time in more than `13` `digits`. `CurrentTime= 1357755780000`, `StartingTime=1357602840`, `EndingTime=1357756140`

But when I do comparison in below code, the `if` part is not executed, only the `else` part is executed.

Is there any mistake in my code? I want to make currentTime in 10 digits. So I think, conversion of date format to milliseconds is wrong.

```
 String toParse = getDateorTime(1) + " " + getDateorTime(2);
 long currentTime=0,startingTime=0,endingTime=0,milliseconds=0;
 try 
 {
    dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd hh:mm"); 
    Date date = null;
    try {
       date = dateFormater.parse(toParse);
       date.setTime(milliseconds);
    }catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("\n Error in date parsing"+e.toString());
    }
    currentTime = (date.getTime());
    start=Long.parseLong((cursor.getString(5).trim()));
    end=Long.parseLong((cursor.getString(6).trim()));
 }catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
 }

 if((currentTime>=startingTime)&&(currentTime<=endingTime))
 {
   //
 }
```

Comment: try to post remaining code like where cursor initialized etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your examples, you actually have `startingTime` and `endingTime` in SECONDS, while you're comparing it to `currentTime` in MILLISECONDS. Simply multiply the second-times by 1,000, like so:

```
if((currentTime>=startingTime*1000L)&&(currentTime<=endingTime*1000L))
```

Comment: starting time and ending time in milliseconds only

Comment: Everything is in milliseconds only yar. Current, starting and ending time. When i do compare "if part" is not executing only else part has been executed. Current Time= 13577598690000, StartingTime=1357602840,EndingTime=1357842540

Comment: Correct -- StartingTime and EndingTime is in SECONDS. Just add three zeroes to either, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide by `1000`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the long values to string and if length is >10 simply substring the value (0,10) and then you can use string .equals too or covert them back to long for comparison .